# how to post a href value via jquery ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, post

How to post each value `apple` or `pear` or `banana` to `data.php` via jquery ajax? Thanks.

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function(){
      $.get('data.php', {'page':$(this).text()}, function(data){
        $('#content').html(data);
      });                         
    });
 });
</script>
<a href="#">apple</a>
<a href="#">pear</a>
<a href="#">banana</a>
<div id="content"></div>
```

data.php

```
<?
$page = strtoupper($_GET['page']);//$_GET['page'] should be apple or pear or banana
if(isset($page)){
    $html  = "<h3>".$page."</h3>";  
    $html .= "<p>Hi... this is a ".$page."</p>";
    print($html);
}
?>
```

Comment: The code you have given has no errors.

example

http://decad.kodingen.com/bugs/jqueryget.html ...What are you getting?

Comment: @Decad Thanks, I have found the reason. don not laugh me, my notebook Wireless is instability, and I use `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` The jquery min load failed from google caused error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function(){
      var that = this;
      $.get('data.php', {'page':$(that).text()}, function(data){
        $('#content').html(data);
      });                         
    });
 });
```

Cheers